# How do we label a matrix plot with a predefined list of labels (e.g. a list of prime numbers)?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis-labels

I have a [CSV File with elliptic curve related data](https://sultanow.info/misc/public/elliptic_curves.csv) which looks as follows (excerpt):

```
3,19,[(1,4,1),(4,7,44)]
3,13,[(4,1,10)]
5,11,[(4,39,14)]
3,7,[(1,2,1),(1,3622,111),(4,17,10)]
3,5,[(4,1,2),(4,959,124)]
3,23,[(3,5,2)]
5,13,[(2,7,2),(2,8,1),(2,47,70),...]
7,11,[(1,2,1),(1,13,2),(1,53,4),...]
3,29,[(4,13,4)]
5,17,[(2,2,3),(4,6881,498)]
5,19,[(4,71,18)]
3,37,[(4,25,14)]
7,17,[(4,19,30)]
7,19,[(3,66,5)]
```

The first and second number in each line forms a pair of odd prime numbers and the list after these two primes is used to specify the color of the corresponding matrix cell. I want to generate a matrix plot where the x-axis and y-axis are labeled with the first 200 (odd) primes: `3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, ..., 1193, 1201, 1213, 1217, 1223, 1229`. The following code works fine to generate the colorized matrix plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from sympy import sieve, prime
import itertools
import pandas as pd

matrix_size = 200
matrix = np.zeros((matrix_size, matrix_size))

with open('C:/Users/esultano/git/elliptic_curves/data/elliptic_curves.csv') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        p, q, cases = eval(line)
        idx_p = sieve.search(p)[0]-2
        idx_q = sieve.search(q)[0]-2
        if idx_p < matrix_size and idx_q < matrix_size:
            cases_set = set()
            for case in cases:
                cases_set.add(case[0])
            cases_list = list(cases_set)
            val = sum(i*i for i in cases_list)
            matrix[idx_p,idx_q] = val
            matrix[idx_q,idx_p] = val

max_prime = prime(matrix_size+2)
axis_labels = list(sieve.primerange(3, max_prime))

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
matrix_plot = ax.matshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_xticklabels(axis_labels)
ax.set_yticklabels(axis_labels)
plt.show()
```

The plot looks as follows:

[image]

Unfortunatelly the axis labeling is not correct since each axis should span the primes from `3` to `1229`. How can I fix the axis labeling? I am not requiring to place each of these 200 primes as axis label (displaying a few labels would be fine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documentation of [Axes.set_xticklabels()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticklabels.html) says, obligatory you have to call [Axes.set_xticks()](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xticks) before.

I did necessary modifications to your code, so that it works now. Screenshot of output goes after code.

In my code you can see `// 9`, because of this 10 primes (ticks) on axis is shown. If you want e.g. 20 numbers then do `// 19`, etc.

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow73632991#main.py) and [See diffs](https://www.diffchecker.com/xzHd1Wmm)

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.pyplot import figure
from sympy import sieve, prime
import itertools
import pandas as pd

matrix_size = 200
matrix = np.zeros((matrix_size, matrix_size))

with open('elliptic_curves.csv') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        p, q, cases = eval(line)
        idx_p = sieve.search(p)[0]-2
        idx_q = sieve.search(q)[0]-2
        if idx_p < matrix_size and idx_q < matrix_size:
            cases_set = set()
            for case in cases:
                cases_set.add(case[0])
            cases_list = list(cases_set)
            val = sum(i*i for i in cases_list)
            matrix[idx_p,idx_q] = val
            matrix[idx_q,idx_p] = val

max_prime = prime(matrix_size+2)
axis_labels = list(enumerate(sieve.primerange(3, max_prime)))
axis_labels = axis_labels[::len(axis_labels) // 9][:-1] + [axis_labels[-1]]
ticks = [e[0] for e in axis_labels]
ticklabels = [e[1] for e in axis_labels]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
matrix_plot = ax.matshow(matrix, interpolation='nearest')
ax.set_xticks(ticks); ax.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)
ax.set_yticks(ticks); ax.set_yticklabels(ticklabels)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]